# is it possible to extract multiple segments from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

example:  I'm trying to return "abcdijklqrstyz" from the string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
I've tried str.splice but that only allows me to extract sequential characters.

Comment: Please reword your question and follow [SO Formatting Guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for Regular Expressions (regex). Here is an example of how to get what you requested in your example.

```
var match = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.match(/^(.{4})(?:.{4})(.{4})(?:.{4})(.{4})(?:.{4})(.+)$/);
match.shift(); // This removes the passed in string from the results, leaving the matches
console.log(match.join(''));
```

The expression can be broken down to the following: `^` starts the match criteria at the beginning of the string [or line]. `(.{4})` does a couple of things. The parenthesis make the content of the match end up in it's own "capture group". `.` means "match any character except newlines (pretty much)". `{4}` means match the following sequence a total of 4 times, no more and no less. The rest of the string is just a permutation of that. The only other differences you'll find are `(?:` which means it's a non-capture group and the contents will not be returned. This could have been omitted but for some people it provides more clarity when reading. Finally, `$` at the very end means "end the match at the very end of the string [or line]".

See the example in action and play around with it here: https://regex101.com/r/X54DKC/1. There is also great documentation on building regular expression. Here is a great tutorial site: https://regexone.com/.